# Python/Spyder Error for .csv file

Tags: python, spyder

I'm just starting out learning Python/Spyder. I have completed a few classes in R for data science.

Below is failing with the error: IOError: File APPL.csv does not exist

However, my script and .csv file are in the same folder. Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

```
    import pandas as pd

     def test_run():
         df = pd.read_csv("APPL.csv")
         print df

     if __name__ == "__main__":
          test_run()
```

Comment: use absolute paths

Comment: https://chrisalbon.com/python/pandas_dataframe_importing_csv.html

Comment: I tried this and received the same error: IOError: File C:/Users/jwalt/.spyder/data/APPL.csv does not exist

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

Try it by inserting the file pathway. For example:

```
    pdf = pd.read_csv('../data/example.csv')
    df
```

Careful if the pathway has a '/r' since it is usually interpreted as a special character carriage return. You can add 'r' prefix to your string literals which can prevent that. Example:

```
    path = r"foo\rar"
```

Double check to make sure the file pathway is correct if it still errors out reboot and try again.

Comment: DO the script and .csv need to be in the same path? For some reason it doesn't matter what path the .csv file is in, it errors out.

Comment: It needs the full path to the file. If its in the same project do something like `file_name = os.path.sep.join(os.getcwd(), 'csvs/example.csv')`

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the problem probably by expanding to full path using

```
import os.path
os.path.abspath('./AAPL.csv')
```